# Views 3, empty page returns page not found instead of empty text

Tags: 7, views

I am using Views 3 on Drupal 7.

I have created a view page and gave a path. I have set to display full content. 
I have then added a NID contextual filter and set provide default value through PHP code. I am then using PHP to generate a list of nodes to show.

When there are nodes the page loads correctly.

When there are no nodes the page returns 'page not found'.

I have no results behaviour to print text saying no results are found, but this does not show.
I then added a header/footer and enabled 'Display even if the view has no result', these do not get displayed.

I have set a page title but this also displays as 'page not found' rather than the set title.

How can I get the view page to display even if there are no results?

Comment: Are you sure you have not set it to "page not found" in your contextual filter setting?

Comment: @nhck, Hi, I can't see that option. I have added conextual filter Nid, selected PHP value, enabled multiple values. When PHP returns nodes it displays the nodes.

Comment: I was referring to the contextual filter setting called "When the filter value is NOT available" -> then you choose an option. But don't know about the php value there..